# Dynamic sized container relative to a static one

Tags: css, layout

I was trying to build a simple layout, but I got stuck into finding a reliable css hack.

What I need is a big container with dynamic width, which has two columns. The one on the right is basically a sidebar, with a fixed width. The one on the left is the content area, which needs to be sized relative.

But I can't assign a percentage to it. If the big container were 80% of the page (let's say 600px in a certain case), and the sidebar were 200px in fixed width, then, the left column should have been 66% (400px). But that had to change everytime, since the big container itself is relative, and it wouldn't have always been 600px.

So, if the big container were 1000px, then, the left column should have been (1000-200) 800px, which is 80%. So I'm guessing that it is some kind of double relation.

I can accomplish the effect with JavaScript. I would create a function which calculates the free space into the container and assign it to the left column, and call this function once on initialization and once in a resize listener.

But this method lacks of performance in speed terms. And sometimes it is buggy. I was wondering how could I do that with pure CSS. If you check out Youtube's homepage you will find out what I mean. The column on the left and the column on the right (recommended channels) have a static width. However, the main area in the middle still manages to have a relative width.

HTML:

```
   <div id="main">

     <div id="left">
     </div>

     <div id="right">
     </div>

   </div>
```

CSS:

```
   #main
   {
      width: 80%;
      min-height: 1000px;
   }

   #left, #right
   {
      float: left;
      height: auto;
   }

   #right
   {
      width: 200px;
   }

   #left
   {
      /* how can I make this relative to its parent and in the same time not push the righ column, which will, at some point, be too big for the container? */
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

### HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">SideBar</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: green;
}
.sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.content {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/LAA6J/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` to position your divs appropriately:

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4zFeC/

```
 #main {
     width: 80%;
     min-height: 100px;
     border:4px solid blue;
     display:table;
 }
 #left, #right {
     min-height: 100px;
     display:table-cell;
 }
 #right {
     width: 200px;
     border:4px solid red;
 }
 #left {
     border:4px solid green;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've actually tried something like this, but I didn't use `display: table-cell` so I just thought that wasn't the solution.

Comment: @AndreiPham This works fine but you may want to check out my solution. Its simpler and does the same thing.